# How to adjust the curve of a sine wave formula?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Apologies to all I'm pretty ignorant to maths beyond high school level. Essentially what I want to do is create a sine wave that's a bit more curvy than just a standard sine wave (see image below)

[image: sine wave vs. more curvy wave image]

I'm using animation software and I can generate a sine wave using a formula. But for design reasons I need it to be curvier. I've hunted around and fiddled with the formula without luck.

This is the default formula that is creating the bottom sine wave in the image:

$$ Sin(u*2.0*\pi)*0.2 $$

Is there any way to change the formula to make it produce a curvier line?

Below is the language the formula parameter accepts. I'm also struggling with how to translate the format of the formulas.

[image: list of accepted mathematical operation in cinema 4d]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but maybe: https://forums.gamesalad.com/discussion/88040/sine-wave-with-half-circle-waves

Comment: Except for a certain interval $[-x, x]$ the curve $\sin (x^n)$ satisfies your requirement and the value of $x$ decreases when the integer $n$ grows.

Comment: I'm partial to the *elastica* (see https://www.levien.com/phd/elastica_hist.pdf Fig. 11 and Sec. 13) but it's probably way more complicated than you need. For a simpler solution, you should try a function of the form $y=f(\sin(x))$, for example $f(t)=\dfrac t{1-a+a|t|}$ with $0\le a\le 1$.

Comment: Ah great, thanks guys. Rahul figure 11 in that document is exactly what I'm after. Any chance you could help me translate these formulas into something my program can understand? I'm struggling to format the exponent correctly using their system, does that image above make sense to you guys?